# TS2304: Cannot find name 'Rx'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I came across some code in Angular that rotates between words every few seconds:

```
words: string[] = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
word = null;

rotateWords() {
  const source = Rx.Observable.interval(1000).take(this.words.length);
  const sub = source.finally(this.rotateWords).subscribe(i => this.word = this.words[i]));  
}
```

Unfortunately, I get the error message "**Rx is not found**" in on my version of Rx (6.5.5) and Angular (10.0.9). The code seems to be written in an old-style of RxJs. How do I rewrite it in the new style?

Comment: How are you including Rx? An `import`? A `require`?

Comment: There is currently no option to import it on my IDE (Webstorm)

Comment: Sorry I don't mean the IDE, I mean the actual application. For example, when I want to use the `range` function from Rx, I will do something like `import { range } from "rxjs";`.

Comment: I get the error: `Module '"../../../../node_modules/rxjs"' has no exported member 'Rx'.` when I try `import { Rx } from 'rxjs';`.

Comment: Try `import { Observable } from 'rxjs'` and then just use `Observable.interval(1000)...`

Comment: Thanks, I now get `TS2339: Property 'interval' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.` I think the manner in which the code is written reflects an old style of RxJs.

Comment: First of all, I'd start with a new ´npm install´. Also I don't know what code editor you're using but probably the most used is Visual Studio Code and VSCode happens to provide an import suggestion if the classname is not found within your component. Otherwise, I'd recommend looking at the `node_modules` folder and see where the function/class is located that you're trying to use and make sure the path is correct. Otherwise, reffering to the public.api file should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using angular with **rxjs 4+**

```typescript
import { interval } from 'rxjs'
import { take, finalize} from 'rxjs/operators'

words: string[] = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
word = null;

rotateWords() {
    const source = interval(1000).pipe(take(this.words.length));
    const sub = source.pipe(finalize(this.rotateWords.bind(this))).subscribe(i => {
      this.word = this.words[i];
    });
  }
}
```

[See Below Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rhjnqv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks, I am getting some errors on the second line: `const sub...` around `error TS1135: Argument expression expected.

19     const sub = source.pipe(finally(this.rotateWords)).subscribe(i => this.word = this.words[i]));`

Comment: I have changed `finally` to `finalize` as this was renamed

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and the above and it doesn't seem to look. When it gets to the last word, I get the error `1 errors occurred during unsubscription:
1) TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: Sorry meant to say, it doesn't seem to "loop"

Comment: Please check now, I binded `this`